# XsltViwerWebPart in SharePoint 2016

Tags: development, 2016

As documentation link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.xsltlistviewwebpart?view=sharepoint-server

I added the  Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages reference for XsltViwerWebPart in SharePoint 2016 solution.

However, I get a reference error for  XsltViwerWebPart

What's the correct namespace?

How can I use XsltViewerWebPart in SP 2016?

Answer (score 0):

You need add Microsoft.SharePoint.dll into References in visual studio solution.

And then add the code below to .cs file.

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages;
```

If you want to use XsltListViewWebPart, the following example for your reference.

**[Programmatically Adding XsltListViewWebPart Inside Panel in SharePoint](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/sagarp/programmatically-adding-xsltlistviewwebpart-inside-panel-in/)**

Comment: Thanks for your input, I added microsoft.sharepoint reference, still can't find it at SP solution 2016